# Lenovo X220 i7 Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, thinkpad, sandy-bridge

I am thinking about switching back to the newest Ubuntu 13.10 on my x220. I had different Ubuntu releases installed before and quite liked it. Main problem was always the power management of the i7 CPU. After looking around different Ubuntu and ThinkPad Communities I am still not sure if the problem has been solved with this - or previous releases.

Will there still be any known problems with the power saving / cpu throtteling / fan control on x220´s with i7 cpu??

Comment: What kind of power management issues did you have? I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on an i5 X230 and have no problems with the power management.

Comment: I remember that at the time when I was running it - about 1,5 to 2 years back - I was always wondering why my x220 got that hot and the fan was basically running at 100% all the time. Afterwards I found out that there is special fan control, which is not solving the problem, that the CPU is not beeing throttled correctly.

Is it working out of the box right now?

Comment: I can hardly hear the fan on my X230. I'm using the [tlp power manager](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) for advanced power saving options and I've had no problems so far. I don't think it's been too loud before I installed tlp either. I'm not sure if there would be any difference with an i7 CPU though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a problem like you describe is likely to be present. A bug report describing the issue is here, and still an open issue for the Linux kernel:

"i915 doesn't reach RC6 state after s2ram - Thinkpad T420, X220"
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48791

Answer (score 0):

It will work wonderfully, just install TLP from http://linrunner.de this app has been made for Thinkpads but works with all laptops. On my ASUS i7s I get the same battery life as on Windows 8.